# Position sticky contained within element?

Tags: html, css

This is probably due to my inexperience with this new CSS rule but for whatever reason the nav I have set to `position: sticky;`, for lack of better words, doesn't follow the entire page?

I'm unsure why and was wondering if anyone could help clarify why I am
getting this behaviour. [This is a link to my developer space.](http://letty.c0843711.myzen.co.uk/)

```css
.cd-header {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0; /* required */
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<header class="cd-header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="img/logo/cd-logo-lr-stky.svg" alt="Continuum Digital Logo" class="brand-logo"></a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="#navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
           <div class="hamburger hamburger--spin">
            <div class="hamburger-box">
              <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </button>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">
                <i class="now-ui-icons location_compass-05"></i>
                Our Journey
              </a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">
                <i class="now-ui-icons files_single-copy-04"></i>
                Blog
              </a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link n-btn" href="#">
                <i class="now-ui-icons arrows-1_share-66"></i>
                Build Your Quote
              </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Please update your code to be a [mcve]; right now it does not reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Thats why I linked to the site itself, I'm not sure I can replicate the behaviour outside of my developer site.

Comment: Linking to a site is not adequate per the rules of Stack Overflow. When your site goes down, this question becomes useless to other readers and unanswerable. You need to include the code required to reproduce your error *in the question itself*.

Comment: Ok by that logic I need to replicate an error of which. I'm looking for an answer for here? if I could do that I wouldn't need to ask the question...

Comment: The fact that many people might solve their own problem by creating an MCVE is a large point of the MCVE. The issue remains, however, that if you cannot reproduce your error then how do you expect us to? You should be able to copy all your site HTML and all your site CSS into the question, pare it down until you only have enough code to reproduce the problem, and then click "post". What about that process makes you think asking is superfluous?

Comment: The point being that you expect everyone on this site to be a senior developer with skills that match that of the most experienced devs.  Some users are the new guys and many of us are learning, including myself. Being mostly self taught means sometimes you are not able to break code down easily and spending months in documentation doesn't always mean it'll stick with you.

Comment: Just because your expect someone to do know something doesn't mean they will. Have some curtesy for the new guy.

Comment: I have given you the courtesy of not downvoting your question, even though it does not show sufficient effort. We *don't* expect you to be a senior developer or solve every problem possible without assistance. That would be silly. We simply ask that you follow the prescribed guidelines when asking a debugging question. We cannot debug a problem with code if you don't give us the code. It's really not complicated. Also, I see you have not taken the [tour]; for having been around Stack Overflow for over 4 years, I really recommend you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `position:sticky` works till its related containing block height passed...

In your example `.cd-header` has a parent(containing block) `body` with `height:100` which is taking only viewport height...thats why your `.cd-header` is no more sticky after that height value is passed...

So try to remove `height:100%` from body or set it to `auto`...

```
body {
  height:auto;
}
```

You can read more about `position:sticky` from **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**